# Google Maps DirectionsService multiple calls

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Does anyone know why this is only giving me directions for n+1 routes.  For example from A-B-C-D-E-F, it will give me the following routes:

A-B

B-C (empty result)

C-D

D-E (empty result)

E-F

Here's my google maps code, and I'm calling it with (inside a UIWebView):

showDirections([A, B, C, D, E], true);

```
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

function showDirections(locations, metric) {

var units = metric ? google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC : google.maps.UnitSystem.IMPERIAL;

for (i=0; i<locations.length-1; i++) {


    console.log('navigating: '+locations[i].title+' to '+locations[i+1].title);

    var request = {
        origin: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i].location.lat, locations[i].location.lng),
        destination: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i+1].location.lat, locations[i+1].location.lng),
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING,
        avoidHighways: !!(locations[i].avoidHighway),
        unitSystem: units
    };

    setTimeout(function() { getDirections(request); }, 2000);

}

window.location = 'directionsstatus://LOADED';

}

function renderDirections(directions) {
    var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
    directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('panel'));
    directionsDisplay.setDirections(directions);
}

function getDirections(request) {
    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            renderDirections(response);
        } else {
            alert(status);
            window.location = 'directionsstatus://' + status;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Have you tried requesting a single route -  A - F, that must pass through the waypoints of B, C, D, and E?

Comment: Hey Adam, I have tried that but I want to be able to specify to avoidHighways between A-B/B-C/C-D if necessary.  Does the waypoint object support an avoid parameter?